# How to add type to graphql schema using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

i have a query like below

```
query MyQuery($id: ID!) {
    something(id: $id) {
        details {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

and in the types.graphql i have

```
type something {
    details: // this should either type details1 or type details2 
}

type details1 {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
}

type details2 {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
    other: string!
}
```

so the type details can be either of type details1 or details2

how can i specify that in the type something for details field.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**

i have tried something like below

```
type something {
    details : details1 | details2;
}
```

but this doesnt work.

what i can possibly do is create another type

```
type details3 {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
    other: string
}
```

which is a combination of details2 and details3

and use it like

```
type something {
    details: details3
}
```

but dont want to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a union

```
type something {
    details : details;
}

union details = details1 | details2
```

Comment: thanks. but how do i read the details field in query. i have tried using union and it gives error cannot query id and name on type details1 or details2. did you mean to use an inline fragment on details1 or details2

Comment: yes you use an inline fragment to choose between details1 and details two fields

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed the `=` symbol when defining a type,
I've just tried this and it worked:

```js
type details1 = {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
}

type details2 = {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
    other: string
}

type something = {
  details: details1 | details2;
}

const test: something = {
  details: {
    id: 'abc',
    name: 'abc',
    description: 'abc',
  }
}


const test2: something = {
  details: {
    id: 'abc',
    name: 'abc',
    description: 'abc',
    other: 'abc'
  }
}
```